# Trying to setup tests with mocha, babel & es6 modules

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, babeljs

I'm trying to leverage grunt & babel to load my es6 source as a dependency for the given test. So i've been running the actual src and compiling the app just fine via browserify:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Import dependencies
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

  grunt.initConfig({
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'www/js/bundle.js': ['src/app.js'],
        },
        options: {
          transform: [['babelify', { optional: ['runtime'] }]],
          browserifyOptions: {
            debug: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    jshint : {
      options : {
        jshintrc : ".jshintrc",
      },

      dist: {
        files: {
          src: ["src/**/*.js"]
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: ['src/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'browserify'],
        options: {
          atBegin: true,
          spawn: true
        },
      },
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("default", ['watch']);

};
```

It compiles a single bundle.js file, which i include in my index.html file. Great!

So what I want to do from the tests, is import the file i'm testing. So i have a simple storage object called InteractionStore, locationed in `src/stores/interaction_store.js`. Then i have created a spec file at: `test/stores/interaction_store_spec.js`

```
import expect from "expect.js";
import InteractionStore from '../../../src/stores/interaction_store.js';

describe("InteractionStore", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    InteractionStore.data = [];
  });
  describe("#start()", () => {
    it ("should apped multiple", function () {
      InteractionStore.start();
      InteractionStore.start();
      InteractionStore.start();
      expect(InteractionStore.data.length).toEqual(3);
    });
  });
});
```

So i import the store directly. I've added a few sections to the grunt file for the test process:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Import dependencies
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');

  grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        modules: "common"
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test',
          src: ['**/*.js'],
          dest: 'test/compiled_specs',
          ext:'.js'
        }]
      }
    },
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'www/js/bundle.js': ['src/app.js'],
        },
        options: {
          transform: [['babelify', { optional: ['runtime'] }]],
          browserifyOptions: {
            debug: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    clean: ["test/compiled_specs"],
    jshint : {
      options : {
        jshintrc : ".jshintrc",
      },

      dist: {
        files: {
          src: ["src/**/*.js"]
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: ['src/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'browserify:dist'],
        options: {
          atBegin: true,
          spawn: true
        },
      },
    },

    mochaTest: {
      test: {
        src: ['test/compiled_specs/**/*_spec.js']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("default", ['watch']);
  grunt.registerTask("test", ['clean', 'babel', 'mochaTest']);

};
```

Babel compiles the tests no problem, but then when i run it, it loads the .js files in the src folder that are in es6 still, and naturally it explodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the original problem with help on reddit. Instead of using mocha test, I would run the mocha command directly:

```
mocha --ui tdd --compilers js:babel/register test/**/*.js
```

One can easily add that in as an npm script.

Further more because i'm testing a cordova project, I needed phantom js. This took some figuring out as well, much help from this gist here: https://gist.github.com/nmabhinandan/6c63463d9f0987020c6f. But here's my final setup in case anyone is interested:

Folder structure:

```
src/
  -- app code
test/
  spec/
    stores/
      interaction_store_spec
  SpecRunner.js
tests.html

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Import dependencies
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

  grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        modules: "amd"
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ["test/**/*.js"],
          dest: "dist",
          ext: ".js"
        }, {
          expand: true,
          src: ["src/**/*.js"],
          dest: "dist",
          ext: ".js"
        }]
      }
    },
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'www/js/bundle.js': ['src/app.js'],
        },
        options: {
          transform: [['babelify', { optional: ['runtime'] }]],
          browserifyOptions: {
            debug: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    clean: {
      test: ["dist/test"]
    },
    eslint : {
      target: ["src/**/*.js"]
    },
    exec: {
      run_tests: "node_modules/.bin/mocha-phantomjs -p $(which phantomjs) tests.html"
    },
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
          'www/css/styles.css': 'www/css/sass/styles.scss'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      css: {
        files: ['www/css/sass/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass']
      },
      scripts: {
        files: ['src/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['eslint', 'browserify:dist'],
        options: {
          atBegin: true,
          spawn: true
        },
      },
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("default", ['sass','watch']);
  grunt.registerTask("test", ["clean", "babel:test", "exec:run_tests"]);
};
```

The important thing to note from the gruntfile is the use of babel itself rather than browserify. I also added mocha-phantom and requirejs to support the tests. The watch, sass, and eslint are only used for building the source to run the app. The babel compiles the source & tests to AMD modules. When using requirejs, you must drop extensions in your import strings. It works for browserify, but requirejs will not use the baseUrl in the SpecRunner if it has an extension.

SpecRunner.js:

```
// RequireJS configuration
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'dist/test',
  urlArgs: 'cb=' + Math.random(),
  paths: {
    spec: 'spec', // lives in the test directory
  },
  hbs: {
    disableI18n: true
  }
});

let testSuite = {
  specs: [
    'spec/stores/interaction_store_spec'
  ]
};

// run mocha
(function() {
  require(testSuite.specs, function() {

    if (window.mochaPhantomJS) {
      mochaPhantomJS.run();
    } else {
      mocha.run();
    }

  });
})();
```

Tests.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/expect.js/index.js"></script>

    <script>
        mocha.ui('bdd');
        mocha.reporter('html');
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js" data-main="dist/test/SpecRunner"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Package json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.8.12",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.12",
    "babelify": "^6.1.3",
    "eslint": "^0.24.1",
    "expect.js": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-babel": "^5.0.1",
    "grunt-browserify": "^3.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-eslint": "^16.0.0",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "mocha-phantomjs": "^3.6.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.20"
  }
}
```

So when i run the `grunt test` or `grunt babel` more specifically, i get a dist folder in the root of my app:

```
 dist/
   test/
     -- compiled specs
   src/
     -- compiled source
```

And then phantom runs the specs just fine. Note you'll need to have phantomjs installed through homebrew or something like that to get this to work. I used 1.9.2